# Herobox can't be dismissed due to JavaScript error

Tags: bug, user-interface

This box (that is shown to anyone who's not logged in) cannot currently be dismissed:

[image: herobox screenshot]

Clicking the black icon in the top right corner prints the following error in the developer console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: l.split is not a function (full-anon.en.js?v=8d4ab4c4ca11:4)
    at Object.t [as dismiss] (full-anon.en.js?v=8d4ab4c4ca11:4)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> ((index):457)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

The behaviour is consistent across Chrome (65.0.3325.124), Firefox (58.0.2), Safari (10.1.2 (12603.3.8)) and Opera (51.0.2830.40), on both macOS and Windows. Other Stack Exchange sites do not seem to be affected.

Comment: Just checked and I also get this error. Very bizarre...